# Extension that allows previewing remote database tables in CKAN

Tags: plugins, ckan

I need connect and preview to a external mysql bbdd so I just installed for CKAN this extension (I have CKAN 2.7.3):
http://extensions.ckan.org/extension/dataproxy/

I followed step by step the tutorial and ckan habilitated the dataproxy buttom.
Firt I filled the form with the correct database and table name to connect with MySQL database but when I add the Database Proxy Explorer View, always alert the same error.

[No module named MySQLdb par1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcEZs.png)

[No module named MySQLdb part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkO9x.png)

[Information in mysqldb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp54p.png)

I used python 2.7 and the module called MySQLdb

I tryed do same changes in the code but not successfully for example delete the module MySQLdb but its totally necesary for the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an ImportError for MySQLdb, so it sounds like you need to install that python library/module. Maybe you missed this step, or forgot to activate the virtualenv beforehand. Anyway this should do it:

```
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I installed mysqlclient out, without my virtualenv activate! A silly mistake!